# How to check if sim card is installed or not

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am developing an app which has call and message functionality , i want to check if sim card is installed or not coz i am facing problem with messaging as it gives alerts for " Message Sent Successful"

Please help me out.

Comment: I think you wanna Detecting SIM card availability.Am i right  ?

Comment: You should not do this, since you app can also run on a iPad WiFi or iPod touch which do not hold sim cards. `MFMessageComposeViewController` has a class method `canSendText ` which will indicate if the device is able to send messages. For check if the device support calling just check wether the `call:` can be opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be different ways but one way is by using `MFMessageComposeViewController` class to see if you can send the text message. If you can then sim is available otherwise not.

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {
    NSLog(@"SIM Available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no SIM card installed");
}
```

In cases you have iMessage available then this might return you true, you could also check if you can make a call, you might want to use `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo` for that purpose.

Comment: I am checking like this if the sim is installed or not, it works fine. but i am getting alert message "Cannot Send Message" "Text message is not available in x device". How can i prevent that kind of alert message??? @nsgulliver

Comment: This code is useful for if you use simulator. Not in a phone.

Comment: @nsgulliver, `canSendText`  is called but I am getting 'MessageComposeResultFailed' status if sim not inserted in my device. and If I  inserted sim in one of my device and send message successfully.I got confused is sim card is necessary for the 'MFMessageComposeViewController' to send a message successfully?can you please explain it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also check using like this.... First read this doc

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596-CH1-SW1

```
NSString *_code = [[[CTCarrier alloc] init] mobileCountryCode];
```

The value for this property is nil if any of the following apply:

The device is in Airplane mode.
There is no SIM card in the device.
The device is outside of cellular service range.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to be sure that device is iPhone (not iPod or iPad) then check if device can make call or not, just like this............

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice].model isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456"]])
     {
         NSLog(@"Device can make call or send message");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Device can not make call or send message");
     }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Device can not make call or send message");
}
```

Hope it will help you........